# Vue3 with @vuepic/vue-datepicker. How to dynamically change datepicker format?

Tags: datepicker, vuejs3

How do I change the format of text input in datepicker dynamically with vue and datepicker component. When annual checkbox is click the format is 'dd MMMM' and when the checkbox is uncheck the format is 'dd MMMM yyyy'.

I am using Vue3 with @vuepic/vue-datepicker package.

Currently I already set the format as reactive value which in my understanding should rerender the component if the value change.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Datepicker v-model="date" autoApply :format="format" />
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" v-model="isAnnual" :value="true"> Annual
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, watch } from 'vue';
import Datepicker from '@vuepic/vue-datepicker';
import '@vuepic/vue-datepicker/dist/main.css';

const date = ref(new Date);
const format = ref('dd MMMM yyyy');
const isAnnual = ref(false);

watch(isAnnual, (val) => {
  if (val) {
    format.value = "dd MMMM"
  } else {
    format.value = "dd MMMM yyyy"
  }
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hate being this guy, but wouldn't it be easier to have a single format for annual and not annual?

But you can always ust the
JSON.syringify(Object)
and attempt to use moment to format.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use ternary operator inside the format value like -

```
<Datepicker v-model="date" autoApply :format="isAnnual ? dd MMMM : dd MMMM yyyy" />
```